# Plotly Mapbox Markers not rendering (other than circle)

Tags: plotly, mapbox-marker

If I modify one of the Plotly examples (["Lines on Mapbox maps using Scattermapbox traces"](https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-mapbox/)) to use a different marker, these markers no longer appear on the map.

How do I get [other kinds of supported markers](https://labs.mapbox.com/maki-icons/) to display?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Circles appear
fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
    mode = "markers+lines",
    lon = [10, 20, 30],
    lat = [10, 20,30],
    marker = {'size': 10, 'symbol':'circle'}))


# Markers do not
fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
    mode = "markers+lines",
    lon = [-50, -60,40],
    lat = [30, 10, -20],
    marker = {'size': 10, 'symbol':'marker'}))

fig.update_layout(
    margin ={'l':0,'t':0,'b':0,'r':0},
    mapbox = {
        'center': {'lon': 10, 'lat': 10},
        'style': "stamen-terrain",
        'center': {'lon': -20, 'lat': -20},
        'zoom': 1})

fig.show()
```

The example code posted by [empet in this forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/scattermapbox-marker-symbol-location-pin/33265) does not render for me at all (other than the title)

Answer (score 1):

- there are multiple issues raised on **plotly** / **mapbox** of symbols not working.  Like you I have found work around to use custom mapbox map does not work
- have taken approach of downloading **Maki** icons and converting them **shapely** / **geopandas** so I can build **geojson** layer
- the SVG conversion process is really from this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301605/how-to-create-shape-in-shapely-from-an-svg-path-element
- main issue with this approach is that it depends on a number of additional libraries
- from **use it** it is simple to use, main downside is the icons do not resize with zoom.  This can be somewhat worked around (see another answer [Plotly - Adding Scatter Geo points and traces on top of Density Mapbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68762104/plotly-adding-scatter-geo-points-and-traces-on-top-of-density-mapbox/68846629#68846629))

```py
import requests
import svgpath2mpl, shapely.geometry, shapely.affinity
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import numpy as np


# download maki icons
# https://github.com/mapbox/maki/tree/main/icons
f = Path.cwd().joinpath("maki")
if not f.is_dir():
    f.mkdir()
f = f.joinpath("maki.zip")
if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get("https://github.com/mapbox/maki/zipball/main")
    with open(f, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            f.write(chunk)

fz = ZipFile(f)
fz.extractall(f.parent)

def to_shapely(mpl, simplify=0):
    p = shapely.geometry.MultiPolygon([shapely.geometry.Polygon(a).simplify(simplify) for a in mpl])
    p = shapely.affinity.affine_transform(p,[1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0],)
    p = shapely.affinity.affine_transform(p,[1, 0, 0, 1, -p.centroid.x, -p.centroid.y],)
    return p

# convert SVG icons to matplolib geometries and then into shapely geometries
# keep icons in dataframe for further access...
SIMPLIFY=.1
dfi = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.read_xml(sf).assign(
            name=sf.stem,
            mpl=lambda d: d["d"].apply(
                lambda p: svgpath2mpl.parse_path(p).to_polygons()
            ),
            shapely=lambda d: d["mpl"].apply(lambda p: to_shapely(p, simplify=SIMPLIFY)),
        )
        for sf in f.parent.glob("**/*.svg")
    ]
).set_index("name")

# build a geojson layer that can be used in plotly mapbox figure layout
def marker(df, marker="marker", size=1, color="green", lat=51.379997, lon=-0.406042):
    m = df.loc[marker, "shapely"]
    if isinstance(lat, float):
        gs = gpd.GeoSeries(
            [shapely.affinity.affine_transform(m, [size, 0, 0, size, lon, lat])]
        )
    elif isinstance(lat, (list, pd.Series, np.ndarray)):
        gs = gpd.GeoSeries(
            [
                shapely.affinity.affine_transform(m, [size, 0, 0, size, lonm, latm])
                for latm, lonm in zip(lat, lon)
            ]
        )
    return {"source":json.loads(gs.to_json()), "type":"fill", "color":color}

# display all icons to make sure they look ok...
gpd.GeoSeries(
    [
        shapely.affinity.affine_transform(
            s, [1, 0, 0, 1, (i % 20) * 20, (i // 20) * 20]
        )
        for i, s in enumerate(dfi["shapely"])
    ]
).plot()

dfi.loc["karaoke", "shapely"]
```

#### use it

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Circles appear
fig = go.Figure(
    go.Scattermapbox(
        mode="markers+lines",
        lon=[10, 20, 30],
        lat=[10, 20, 30],
        marker={"size": 10, "symbol": "circle"},
    )
)


# Markers do not
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattermapbox(
        mode="markers+lines",
        lon=[-50, -60, 40],
        lat=[30, 10, -20],
        marker={"size": 10, "symbol": "circle"},
    )
)

fig.update_layout(
    margin={"l": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0, "r": 0},
    mapbox={
        "center": {"lon": 10, "lat": 10},
        "style": "stamen-terrain",
        "center": {"lon": -20, "lat": -20},
        "zoom": 1,
    },
)

fig.update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "layers": [
            marker(
                dfi, "soccer", size=.5, color="blue", lon=[10, 20, 30], lat=[10, 20, 30]
            ),
            marker(
                dfi, "star", size=.5, color="red", lon=[-50, -60, 40], lat=[30, 10, -20]
            ),

            
        ]
    }
)
```

#### output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as expained in the topic:

> The example code posted by [empet in this forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/scattermapbox-marker-symbol-location-pin/33265) does not render for me at all (other than the title)

By looking at the browser console logs, I saw these error messages:

```
ERROR: Uses Mapbox map style, but did not set an access token.
ERROR: Missing Mapbox access token.
Mapbox trace type require a Mapbox access token to be registered.
For example:
  Plotly.newPlot(gd, data, layout, { mapboxAccessToken: 'my-access-token' });
More info here: https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-access-token/
```

If you add an access token the example from the forum will render.

Moreover, according to [plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#set-marker-symbols), setting the symbol attribute will only work for Mapbox provided styles, so it won't work for `stamen-terrain`.

Despite this, I still encounter weird issues for specific map-style/marker-symbol combinations.